# Vuetify append item to select menu not selecting as normal item

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a simple select menu using Vuetify (Vue 2.0) seen in fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ku5a6f4/

The option is added, but the menu does not close and select like the other options and the menu stays open

My reference is from the Vuetify docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

under 'prepend/append item slots

```html
<div id="app">
    <v-app dark>
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          clearable
          v-model='selectedItem'
          label="...will 'four' close menu?"
        >

          <template v-slot:append-item>
            <v-divider class="mb-2"></v-divider>
            <v-list-tile >
              <v-list-tile-content>
                four
              </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
          </template>

        </v-select>

    </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    data: {
        items: ["one", "two", "three"],
        selectedItem: ''
    }
});
```

Comment: In provided jsfiddle, you are using sightly outdated vuetify `v0.14.8` and referencing to docs at `v1.5.14` what could cause troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received an answer from Vuetify devs:

I needed to add:
:menu-props="{closeOnContentClick: true}"

```
<v-select
      :items="items"
      clearable
      v-model='selectedItem'
      :menu-props="{closeOnContentClick: true}"
      label="...will 'four' close menu?">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using version `v0.14.8`, not even `v0.15` supports wanted slots. Consider update.

https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/releases/0.15/#/components/selects

Comment: I will update the fiddle. That would explain the discrepency between my production code and fiddle.  ..sucks because I used the vuetify basic fiddle'

Comment: @mattyd in order to make it clickabe, add `@click` event. But i'm not sure if you can add new item that is not in your items neither if you coud close it.

Comment: Yes, I do use a click handler to perform an action in production. It works, but the menu persists after a transition. I would imagine appending an item should behave like an item?